# JavaScript[Konva]: arrayed multiple events only return the last object

Tags: javascript, arrays, events, konvajs

When multiple `Transformer` objects are stored in an array, `on()` event only returns the last object of `transAry`(`transAry[transAry.length-1]`).

```
for (var i = 0; i < transAry.length; i++){
  var trans = transAry[i];
  trans.on('transformer dragmove', function(){
    console.log(trans.x(), trans.y(), trans.scaleX(), trans.scaleY());
  });
}
```

In this case, when moving or sizing each `Transformer` object by mouse operation, `console.log` only shows the last object of `transAry`(`transAry[transAry.length-1]`).

I would like to trigger all the events of the arrayed `Transformer` objects, but I don't know how to do it.

It seems not to be a problem peculiar to *Konva.js*, but I guess it's because I don't understand how JavaScript asynchronous processing works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think , when you using var , and on() is a callback function, so when on() run , for loop is finish and variable trans  = last element in array
=> console.log always return last element in array

i think to fix this, you can be using **let** instead of **var**

Comment: Thank you!
I did it!
Unfortunately I cannot use ES6 syntax because I need to support older browsers.
In particular, it needs to support IE9.
IE always gives me trouble.
If I don't use `let`, do I need to improve the logic?

Comment: That was my misunderstanding. It doesn't need to support IE9 and must support IE11 so, it can be used `let` modifier.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < transAry.length; i++){
  (function(cnt){
    var trans = transAry[cnt];
    trans.on('transformer dragmove', function(){
      console.log(trans.x(), trans.y(), trans.scaleX(), trans.scaleY());
    });
  })(i);
}
```

This is a memo for myself.
It turns out that the same effect can be achieved by confining the callback function inside the immediate function.
The scope of `cnt` is limited into the immediate function.